# jenkins NullPointerException CauseAction load xml

Tags: jenkins, nullpointerexception

Start the jenkins(Jenkins ver. 2.7.4) then the  catalina.out have some errors:

```
Sep 27, 2016 7:30:01 PM hudson.model.Run onLoad
WARNING: failed to load hudson.model.CauseAction@7415bf4 from /home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/vs-server-developer/builds/13/build.xml
java.lang.NullPointerException
at hudson.model.CauseAction.onLoad(CauseAction.java:123)
at hudson.model.Run.onLoad(Run.java:352)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.onLoad(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:151)
at hudson.model.RunMap.retrieve(RunMap.java:225)
at hudson.model.RunMap.retrieve(RunMap.java:57)
at jenkins.model.lazy.AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.load(AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.java:465)
at jenkins.model.lazy.AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.load(AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.java:448)
at jenkins.model.lazy.AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.getByNumber(AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.java:356)
at jenkins.model.lazy.AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.search(AbstractLazyLoadRunMap.java:332)
at jenkins.model.lazy.LazyBuildMixIn$RunMixIn.getPreviousBuild(LazyBuildMixIn.java:357)
...
```